# Counting characters in a word

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I want to create a program to output the number of occurrences of a letter in a word. Basicaly the output has to look like this:

```
Please enter a word—howdy
The word howdy has five characters.
What letter would you like to guess? (enter zero to quit) a
There are 0 A’s.
What letter would you like to guess? (enter zero to quit) b
There are 0 B’s.
```

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterOccurence
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    String letter;

    int letterNumber;

    boolean [] alphabet = new boolean [27];

    System.out.println("Please enter a word- ");
    word=input.next();

    System.out.println("The word  "+ word + " has " + word.length() + " letters\n");

    String lower = word.toLowerCase();

    for(letterNumber=0;letterNumber<lower.length();letterNumber++)
        {
            alphabet[lower.charAt(letterNumber) - 'a'] = true;
        }

    //do
    //{
    System.out.println("What letter would you like to guess? (enter 0 to quit) ");
    letter = input.next();

    if (alphabet[letter.charAt(0)-'a'] = true)
      {
        System.out.printf("There are %s's\n",letter.charAt(0));
      }
    else
      {
        System.out.printf("There are 0 %s's\n",letter.charAt(0));   
      } 

    //}while(Character.isLetter(letter.charAt(0))); 
  }
}
```

I am now stuck, any ideas on how to continue?

Comment: You should mention what it is you are stuck on

Comment: Yeah, seems pretty close, what's giving you a problem?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, `boolean`s only hold a `true` or `false` value, you can't count with them. Rather than in your loop setting each element in the array that maps to a certain character to `true`, you could simply increment the counter.

In this case you're going to require an `int` as opposed to a `boolean`. And to print out the amount of occurrences for a specific letter, you obviously just print out the `int` value at that specific index of the array.

An alternative is also a `Map<Character,Integer>`, rather than calculating the index for specific `char`s in your array.

EDIT: As Dave mentioned, your `if` statement is also broken.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, that `if` statement in your commented-out `do/while` is using a single `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison).

All you really need to do is keep a single count per guess, initialize it to zero, and each time you encounter the guessed letter, increment it.

If you're trying to do all that work "up front" before guessing, then you don't really need a map of booleans, you need a map of ints, one per lower-case letter, initialized to zero, and incremented each time its corresponding letter is guessed.

You're very close.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a boolean array for `alphabet` -- that only tells you what letters appear in the word, but not how many of each. Try this instead:

```
boolean [] alphabet = new boolean [27];
for(letterNumber=0;letterNumber<lower.length();letterNumber++)
{
    ++alphabet[lower.charAt(letterNumber) - 'a'];
}
```

Then later:

```
System.out.printf("There are %d %s's\n",alphabet[letter.charAt(0) - 'a'], letter.charAt(0));
```

Comment: The if statement in the second example seems unnecessary. Why not just stick with the one line, the first print statement?

Comment: yup, no need for the "if". the array should be int[], the loop can be char c : lower.toCharArray().

Comment: @AusCBloke - Good point. I changed the code accordingly. I wasn't looking at what OP was doing in the `if`.